# Generic Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I am currently working on implementing some data structures as a way to learn C++. I'm coming mostly from a Java background so I was hoping to get some feedback regarding this implementation of a singly linked list in C++ using templates. This singly linked list will only support insertions at the head and tail positions and deletions from the head position. The plan is to use this as a base to build further data structures. I would like to create a rather complete library of data structures, so I was hoping to make them as extensible and reusable as possible.

Below follows the class definition.

```cpp
#ifndef LINKEDLISTS_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLISTS_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_H_

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename E>
class SinglyLinkedList {

private:

    /** BEGIN NESTED NODE CLASS **/
    class Node {

    private:
        E data; //Should this be a reference?
        Node* next;

    public:
        Node(Node* n, const E& d) : data(d), next(n) {};

        Node* getNext() const { return next; }

        E& getData() { return data; }

        void setNext(Node* n) { next = n; }

    }; /** END NESTED NODE CLASS **/

    /** Begin fields of SinglyLinkedList class **/
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int listSize;
    /** End fields of SinglyLinkedList class **/

public:

    SinglyLinkedList();
    ~SinglyLinkedList();

    //Accessor methods
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    const E& first() const;
    const E& last() const;

    //Update methods
    void addFirst(const E&);
    void addLast(const E&);
    E* removeFirst();

    void print() const;

}; /** END SINGLYLINKEDLIST CLASS HEADER **/

#include "SinglyLinkedList.tpp" //Include implementations of template code.

#endif /* LINKEDLISTS_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_H_ */
```

The implementations of the functions follow below:

```cpp
/*
 * SinglyLinkedList.tpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 5, 2020
 *      Author: dii
 */

/** Constructor **/
template<typename E>SinglyLinkedList<E>::SinglyLinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), listSize(0) {}

/** Destructor **/
template<typename E>SinglyLinkedList<E>::~SinglyLinkedList() {
    while(!isEmpty()) {
        delete removeFirst();
    }
}


/** Begin functions **/


template<typename E> bool SinglyLinkedList<E>::isEmpty() const { return listSize == 0; }

template<typename E> int SinglyLinkedList<E>::size() const { return listSize; }

template<typename E> const E& SinglyLinkedList<E>::first() const { return head->getData(); }

template<typename E> const E& SinglyLinkedList<E>::last() const { return tail->getData(); }

template<typename E> void SinglyLinkedList<E>::addFirst(const E& d) {

    Node* temp = new Node(head->getNext(), d); //Create a new node.
    head = temp; // Set the head pointer to point to this object.
    listSize++; // Increase size of list by 1.

}

template<typename E> void SinglyLinkedList<E>::addLast(const E& d) {

    Node* temp = new Node(nullptr, d);
    if(isEmpty()) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    } else {
        tail->setNext(temp);
        tail = temp;
    }

    listSize++;

}

template<typename E> E* SinglyLinkedList<E>::removeFirst() {

    if(isEmpty()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    E* temp = &(head->getData());
    head = head->getNext();
    listSize--;

    return temp;

}

template<typename E> void SinglyLinkedList<E>::print() const {
    Node* walk = head;
    while(walk != nullptr) {
        std::cout << walk->getData() << std::endl;
        walk = walk->getNext();
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that the destructor is not implemented as well as it could be. I am also still not entirely sure about when to use references, e.g., should the `data` field of the `Node` class be of type `E&` or is just `E` ok?

Comment: A doubly linked list actually makes the whole processes easier.

Comment: Correct, a doubly linked list would be a lot easier, but my idea was to implement a singly linked list to get a general idea of writing this type of data structure in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Design

It's relatively simple to create a double linked list!

---

Some things you should think about some more:

1. Please put your code into a namespace. Do you think that `SinglyLinkedList` is a very unique name in the global scope?
2. You need to look into const correctness.
3. You need to look into move semantics.

---

Major Bug.

You have not implemented the rule of three (or five). When a class contains an owned pointer the compiler generated copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor are not going to work correctly.

Your `SinglyLinkedList` contains the owned pointer: `head`. An owned pointer is one that you have taken responsibility for the lifespan of (and are thus going to call delete on it when it the object is destroyed.

```
{
     SinglyLinkedList<int>    list1;
     list1.addFirst(1);

     SinglyLinkedList<int>    list2(list1);
}
// This code is broken as you have a double delete.
```

---

Upgrade you need to do.

The standard library defines things called concepts. A concept is a set of properties that a class has. One of the big concepts of the standard is the concept of a "Container" (of which a singly linked list is). Ao you should probably make your list "Container" compliant.

## Code Review

I hate useless comments.

```
    /** BEGIN NESTED NODE CLASS **/
    class Node {
```

That counts as a useless comment.

---

OK good start.

```
        Node(Node* n, const E& d) : data(d), next(n) {}   ;
                 // Not Needed                           ^^^
```

But it does mean that you are required to copy the object into the list. Modern C++ has the concept of move semantics. So you should allow for moving the object into the list.

```
        Node(Node* n, E&& d) : data(std::move(d)), next(n) {}
```

Also you should allow the object to be constructed in place:

```
        template<typename... Args>
        Node(Node* n, Args&&... args)
            : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            , next(n)
        {}
```

---

Here you get a reference to the object.
That's fine.

```
        E& getData() { return data; }
```

But what happens if your list has been passed by const reference to a function. Now you can no longer accesses the data as you can't get a const reference to the data.

```
        E const& getData() const {return data;}
```

Its a bit strange that you only return reference from the node. But you return only const references from the list?

```
    const E& first() const;
    const E& last() const;
```

---

I actually hate your get/set mentatility here. I see no need for it inside the node object itself.

```
        void setNext(Node* n) { next = n; }
```

---

That's fine.

```
    void print() const;
```

But two things to note.

1. There is more streams than the `std::cout` so allow this to be pramertized.
2. The normal way of streaming is via the output operator: `operator<<()`

   ```
   void print(std::ostream& stream = std::cout);
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, SinglyLinkedList const& data)
   {
       data.print(str);
       return str;
   }
   ```

---

Answer (score 1):

`forward_list` exists, so I assume this is a learning exercise?

---

style nit:
You're using nonstandard naming conventions compared to the STL; though many people don't like those anyway. `addFirst` may be surprising to readers who are more used to something like "push front" or "enqueue".

---

You're not deleting head here. std::unique_ptr could help here, but might not make sense if you're doing this as an exercise. Still, you should try to figure out a way to prevent memory leaks in a robust way.

```
template<typename E> E* SinglyLinkedList<E>::removeFirst() {

    if(isEmpty()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    E* temp = &(head->getData());
    head = head->getNext();
    listSize--;

    return temp;

}
```

---

This interface only supports storing const values that are copy-constructable. This is a severe limitation -- you wouldn't be able to make a list of `std::unique_ptr`s for example, because those cannot be copied. Supporting non-copyable types would be a good exercise (see forward_list for reference).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes, this is an exercise ultimately, but I would like it to be as legit, robust, and complete as possible. The naming conventions I am still learning, so thank you for pointing that out. I notice now that there is indeed a memory leak in the ```removeFirst``` function, so I will work on fixing that. I don't particularly understand the part about supporting non-copyable types. Is this due to the fact that the field data in the nested node class is of type ```E``` rather than something like ```E&```?

Comment: Just want to note that `std::forward_list` is designed around splicing, so it omits features (like `size()`) that you would find in a hand-rolled singly linked list because of time/space overhead.

Comment: Consider the signature of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/emplace_front:
This supports types that have no default constructor and no copy-constructor. 

Learning r-value references was very difficult for me, but I now find them stupendously valuable. There's really two things to learn here: why std::forward_list has the interface it does, and separately, how it's implemented.

Comment: Additionally, try making sensible copy and move semantics for the data structure itself. E.g. what happens if you make a SinglyLinkedList<SinglyLinkedList<int>> ? It doesn't *need* to be copyable, but if you don't want it to be, it should be explicitly prevented so that someone using it doesn't make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also still not entirely sure about when to use references, e.g., should the `data` field of the `Node` class be of type `E&` or is just `E` ok?

It should not be stored as a reference.  Using a reference would create ownership and lifetime issues, and can make the class harder to use (since you can't copy or move it).

`addFirst` will crash if the list is empty (when `head` is `nullptr`).

`removeFirst` should not return a pointer.  Currently you leak the memory you allocated for the `Node` that holds the data, and return a pointer to that.  When you fix the memory leak, you'll return a dangling pointer (or, worse, a pointer that the caller will have to delete).  It would be better to return a copy of the item in the list.  If the list is empty, either throw an exception or return a default constructed `T` object.  You will then need to make some changes to your destructor.

Your `while` loop in `print` can be more concisely stated using a `for` loop.

```
template<typename E> void SinglyLinkedList<E>::print() const {
    for (Node* walk = head; walk != nullptr; walk = walk->getNext()) {
        std::cout << walk->getData() << '\n';
    }
}
```

I've also changed the `std::endl` to a `'\n'` character.  Since `endl` flushes the output buffer, there can be performance issues when using it.

You can also look into using rvalue references (`T &&`) for things, which will let you move objects rather than having to copy them.